# jenkins - unable to trigger multiple build steps in parallel using the Execute concurrent builds if necessary

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm executing set of robot framework test cases using Jenkins.

There are two set of test cases, Set1 and Set2, and I want these two tests to go in parallel. So I created two build steps and used the `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` and in the slave I had configured I used the `# of Executors` to 2. we i build it, only the test cases from Set1 is running first and gets completed.

```
Build step1 - Execute window batch command
    robot -d results -i group1 -P path/fldr1/fldr2:4.path/fldr3/fldr4:C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages "path\fldr5\fldr6\fldr7"

Build step2 - Execute window batch command
    robot -d results -i group2 -P path/fldr1/fldr2:4.path/fldr3/fldr4:C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages "path\fldr5\fldr6\fldr7"
```

I want the two set of test cases to run in parallel in the same slave machine.

Comment: Have you tried Pabot?

Comment: Haven't tried pabot, I used Pipeline instead

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that what you want is two concurrent **Jobs** each with a single build step.

Comment: No, i wanted two concurrent builds running on the same Job. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, the number of executors is for Jobs. I don't think the Build steps can run in parallel. Unless you find a Jenkins plugin to do that, I can only think on using `pabot` instead of `robot`.

Comment: I guess,     'pabot' will run test cases within a     '.robot' file in parallel which I don't want. So I made use of     'Jenkins Pipeline' and now I'm able to run multiple builds in parallel on an agent machine.

Answer (score 0):

We use pabot for parallel execution with jenkins.

I think pabot would solve your question.

About Pabot:

> Pabot will split test execution from suite files and not from
>   individual test level. In general case you can't count on tests that
>   haven't designed to be executed parallely to work out of the box when
>   executing parallely. For example if the tests manipulate or use the
>   same data, you might get yourself in trouble (one test suite logs in
>   to the system while another logs the same session out etc.). PabotLib
>   can help you solve these problems of concurrency.

To install Pabot

```
pip install -U robotframework-pabot
```

Example to run pabot

```
pabot --processes 4 --verbose --loglevel TRACE --argumentfile "ArgsFile.args" -d Results  -t test_demo1 Tests\Paralel\ParalelTests.robot
```

For More info Check out 
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for this purpose. Surprisingly that it is deprecated now. I had been used in the past. Everything was working without any issues and it was a good analogy to the pipeline approach.

You can run two jobs in parallel (even the same job with different parameters).
Your configuration can be like:

```
parallel (
    // job 1, 2 will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("job_1", "param_1":"50", "param_2":"true") },
    { build("job_2", "param_1":"42", "param_2":"false") }
)
```